# How to store a group of fields in a variable after a ->get() query

Tags: php, laravel

The following is my query which may output more than one row. I need to store the user_id field in each row in the $send_user_id variable below, so that I will use a foreach loop in the blade. I'm currently receiving (Trying to get property of non-object) error.

```
$j_request = DB::table('grpusrs')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'grpusrs.user_id')
            ->join('groups', 'grpusrs.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->where('groups.owner_id', $user_id)
            ->where('grpusrs.join_request', 1)
            ->get();

      $send_user_id = $j_request->user_id;
```

Also this query joins two tables, so how do I specify the table that has the required field? (i.e. I want the user_id that is in the 'Grpusrs' table not in the 'Groups' table)

Comment: instead of get try ->first();

Answer (score 1):

If you need to retrieve multiple `user_id` you can loop through `$j_request` object and collect every `user_id` inside an array.

```
$j_request = DB::table('grpusrs')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'grpusrs.user_id')
            ->join('groups', 'grpusrs.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->where('groups.owner_id', $user_id)
            ->where('grpusrs.join_request', 1)
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();

$send_user_id = [];

$j_request->each(function($item) use ($send_use_id){
    $send_user_id[] = $item->user_id;
});
```

If you only need one `user_id` you should be more "precisely" in your query (get just one record). After that, you can get `user_id` simply with `$j_request->user_id`

Comment: I receive this error : FatalThrowableError in ProfileController.php line 52:
Call to a member function map() on array

Comment: Are you sure that you're trying to loop `$j_request` collection? Anyway, use each method instead of map.